# how to provide option name instead of option index in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Hi Im trying to select an option from dropdown list

```
Select(driver.find_element_by_id("categorySelect")).select_by_visible_text("Testing")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='categorySelect']/option[6]").click()
```

In above command, the option index will be changing by adding value in drop down list. but i need to select Testing option from drop down list.

How to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following xpath (to match exact text):

```
//select[@id='categorySelect']/option[text()='Testing']
```

or (to match text that contains `Testing`)

```
//select[@id='categorySelect']/option[contains(text(), 'Testing')]
```